# using (IDisposable) in c# factory pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-method, sharepoint

How will this example affect the using implementation in GetSite?

```
public abstract class SPSiteBase
{
    protected abstract string Url { get; set; }

    public abstract SPSite GetSite(string url = null);
}

public class SPSiteFactory : SPSiteBase
{
    protected override sealed string Url { get; set; }

    public override SPSite GetSite(string url = null)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? Url : url))
        {
            return site;
        }
    }

    public SPSiteFactory() { }

    public SPSiteFactory(string url)
    {
        Url = url;
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
SPSiteFactory siteFactory = new SPSiteFactory("http://portalurl/");
SPSite site = siteFactory.GetSite();
```

I've noticed that the code steps out of the using after I run the `siteFactory.GetSite()` method but will the `site` ever be disposed?

Comment: `using { return }` is the same as `try { return }`—it won't magically handle errors the calling code. Thus `using` will dispose right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use a factory to dispose your objects, your code is creating and immediately disposing the SPSite  as soon as it steps out of your method.

```
public override SPSite GetSite(string url = null)
{
    return new SPSite(string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? Url : url))
}
```

Have the disposing be handled by the calling code. You can't handle the disposing from a factory method.

If you want to check it out, build your own disposable type, put a breakpoint in the Dispose method and check for yourself.

Comment: That would make returning disposable variables by using `using` in a factory pattern to an antipattern, that's all I needed, thanks!

Comment: @EricHerlitz I wouldn't say it's an anti-pattern. Anti-pattern is something that works, but is bad design. This code simply doesn't work, it returns an object that's already disposed.

Comment: The instance of `site` still works but the site in the factory is disposed